# Is it possible to have "python3-click-package" and "click 6.6" python 3.4 package at same time in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, click-packages

The "python3-click-package" is necessary for "Click", a package management tool for Ubuntu Touch. While "click 6.6" is a python package on "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/click", which is A simple wrapper around optparse for powerful command line utilities.

I had installed "python3-click-package" and tried to use pip3 to install "click 6.6" for python3.4. However, it will uninstall "python3-click-package" first, and then install "click 6.6".

Is there anyway for me to keep both of them? Would it be a good idea to have "click 6.6" only in python 2.7 environment, which is OK with "python3-click-package"?

PS. In ubuntu 16.04, there is a package "python3-click", which refer to "click 6.6" here. It may not conflict with "python3-click-package".

Comment: Why not just install virtualenv, create and activate a virtualenv and then use pip to install Click in the virtualenv? This is suggested at http://click.pocoo.org/5/quickstart/#virtualenv.

Comment: Yes, the virtualenv is an alternative way. But I am using some python projects to manage onedrive sync, which needs "click 6.6", I am not sure whether it could run in the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to show one possible way to solve the name conflict by renaming the python3 package. Maybe not a good idea.

1. Install the "python3-click-package" for apt-get.
2. Download the source of "click 6.6" and edit the setup.py to give it another name like "clickdev". Then install this "clickdev" package.
3. When I encounter some import errors in python project, I change `import click` to `import clickdev as click`. If there are several projects using "click 6.6", this could be a lot of work.

That's it.